# Fibonocci Generation by Recursion

Tags: java, recursion, fibonacci

I am trying to create a method that will generate a Fibonacci sequence based on user input and calculated to the tenth number, all through recursion. (Learning recursion right now, this is one exercise).

Here is my attempted code, which I am currently struggling to make work:

```
//being run with fibonacci(10, 10);
//Start being the number the sequence starts with
public static int fibonacci(int start, int times) 
{
    if(times > 0)
    {
        int result = fibonacci(start - 1, times - 1) + fibonacci(start - 2, times - 1);
        sequence += result;
        return result;
    }
    System.out.println(sequence);
    return start;
}
```

This, however, returns a large amount (I think about 40,000 numbers taking approximately 10 seconds to run to completion). Also all the numbers appear to be negative, definitely not what my aim was.

Now, on to identifying the problem: I believe the problem is that the method is calling itself twice more every single time it is called, adding up to the large amount. However, I can't think of a way around this seeing as I am trying to do it through recursion each time and I have no choice but to call it again.

As for why it is negative, I haven't a clue. I thought I was using the Fibonacci equation correctly, but obviously I am doing something incorrectly.

Could anyone help me through this please?

(True, I could easily google some code for this as I am sure it is out there, but I want to actually learn how this is done and what I am doing wrong for future reference. Better to advance as a programmer than to get the grade from copied code and move on)

Comment: Hint: Why do you need times and start. In recursion you recurse until you hit a 'base case' where you don't need to anymore - in fibonacci those base cases would be 0 and 1.

Comment: Why Negative? Think about this part `fibonacci(start - 2, times - 1)`. If `start = 10` and `times = 10` first call is `fibonacci(8,9)` next call is `fibonacci(6, 8)`....eventually the last by your condition `times > 0` it will be `fibonacci(-6, 2)` or rather `fibonacci(-8, 1)`

Comment: Have fun with it. When you have it working, time it for the first 40 numbers, then 41, 42, ... Somewhere around 46 the execution time jumps from about ten minutes to enough to exhaust my patience, which was probably several hours.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are a little confused here with what the Fibonacci sequence is.  The formula is F(n) = F(n-1) + F(n-2).  Recursion should always end at a base case which for Fibonacci is F(0) = 0 and F(1) = 1.  Your method only needs one variable which is n.

Think about it this way:

```
public static int fibonacci(int n) {
  //Insert your base cases here to terminate early
  //Then process the recursive formula
  return fibonacci(n - 1) + fibonacci(n - 2);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand what you are trying to do. You want 10 fibonacci numbers from start. Perhaps something like this will work:

```
public static int[] fibonacci(int start, int times) 
{
    return fibonacci(start, times, 0, 1, new int[times]);
}

private static int[] fibonacci(int start, int times, int a, int b, int[] answer) 
{    
    if( start > 0 )
        return fibonacci(start-1, times, b, a+b, answer);

    if( times > 0 )
    {
        answer[answer.length - times] = a;
        return fibonacci(start, times-1, b, a+b, answer);
    }

    return answer;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] a = fibonacci(5, 10);

    for(int i=0; i<a.length; i++)
    {
        System.out.println(a[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Looking at the code I think I understand how you were able to come up with this solution. Thank you a bunch! Took me quite a while of just staring at the code, but I think I get it now.